# user account report in php mysql like bank passbook

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

we create a customer accounting report like bank pass book -

```
| Date |  Debit | Credit | End Balance |

6/7/15    678 Rs    300 Rs       378 Rs    // (End Balance = Debit-Credit)

7/8/15    345 Rs    123 Rs       600 Rs    //(End Balance = (378+345)-123=600) 

4/9/15    123 Rs    70 Rs        653 Rs    //(End Balance = (600+123)-70=653)
```

..............................................

we can eaisly print Date , Credit , Debit Value from Table -

```
     <table>

    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>date</th>
    <th>debit</th>
    <th>credit</th>
    <th>End Balance</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>


    <tbody>
  foreach ($rows as $row):
     <tr>
<td> $rows->date </td>
<td> $rows->debit</td>
<td> $rows->credit</td>
<td>...........</td>
    </tr>
  endforeach;
    </tbody>

        </table>
```

we not understand what mechanism we use , my current end balance always added with last end balance and then minus current credit balance?

Comment: What? What mechanism you use? Could you clarify your issue?

Comment: how my end balance always calculate automatic ,

Answer (score 4):

StackOverflow is not a free code development service, but since I'm in a good mood and feeling generous:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>debit</th>
        <th>credit</th>
        <th>End Balance</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?php 
        $prevBalance = 0;
        foreach($rows as $row): 
            $balance = ($prevBalance + $row->credit) - $row->debit; ?>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo($row->date); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo($row->debit); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo($row->credit); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo($balance); ?></td>
            </tr><?php
        $prevBalance = $balance;
        endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks you very much , i try it..